# Hysteresis loss

Tags: magnetic-fields

It is know that ff an alternating magnetic field is applied to the material, its magnetization will trace out a loop called a hysteresis loop. The lack of retraceability of the magnetization curve is the property called hysteresis and it is related to the existence of magnetic domains in the material. Once the magnetic domains are reoriented, it takes some energy to turn them back again. My question is in a transformer, does the power source drain some current to realign the magnetic domains or it will provide a normal current (sinusoidal) and the magnetic domains wont realign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, power is lost due to hysteresis in the core. The power lost per cycle per unit volume can be calculated using the [Steinmetz equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinmetz%27s_equation):

$$ Q = \eta B^{1.6} $$

and the continuous power loss (in Watts) is:

$$ P = \eta B^{1.6} f V $$

where $f$ is the frequency of the applied voltage and $V$ is the total volume of the core. The parameter $\eta$ is an empirical constant that has to be determined for the core material. The core material is normally chosen to make $\eta$ as small as possible, but it is never zero so some power is always lost. It ends up heating up the core.

Comment: so the voltage source expends some energy (current) to realign the magnetic domains right?

Comment: Yes. That is the mechanism for hysteresis loss.

Comment: The Steinmetz equation is an "engineering equation" which gives approximately useful answers, but requires fitting for both the hysteresis coefficient and the exponent. For example, the factor 1.6 only applies to small sinusoidal currents when you do not saturate the material. The factor $\eta$ is material dependent, and could be very close to zero for some core materials. See for example [this handbook](http://coefs.uncc.edu/mnoras/files/2013/03/Transformer-and-Inductor-Design-Handbook_Chapter_2.pdf) for examples of different materials. The search for efficient cores continues!

Comment: @Floris: agreed!

Answer (score 0):

In order to minimize the effect you describe (which would create significant losses), transformer cores are made of [*soft iron*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_core#Soft_iron) which does not have (much) hysteresis - because there is no (little) permanent magnetization.

Comment: Thank you. But my question is does the voltage source drain some current to realign the magnetic domain?

Comment: Soft iron has no (little) permanent magnetization and therefore no magnetic domains. "Does the voltage source drain current" is a strange question. There will always be _some_ loss in the core; and this loss shows up as a phase shift between voltage and current (ideal unloaded transformer would have 90° phase shift between voltage and current) and a net power flow from voltage source into the transformer.

Comment: I am talking about hysteresis loss and if there's an additional current that will realign the magnetic domain. or the magnetic domains wont be aligned?

Comment: For a material without permanent magnetization, the domains randomize when you remove the coercion (driving current). That doesn't mean you didn't need to use energy to align them; it just means you didn't have to put in additional energy to randomize them. But I don't think you get the energy back...