# Where are the hysteresis losses?

Tags: electromagnetism, dissipation, ferromagnetism

I have some troubles to understand what are the hysteresis losses on a magnetic hysteresis loop of a ferromagnetic material. First question, is there a law which say that the product of the magnetic field B and the magnectic exciation H is equal to power? It is often say that the area under the curve of the magnetic hysteresis loop is equal to energy.

Main question: At which moment occurs hysteresis loss? There are always losses as we polarized the material in one way and after we put this material polarized in the other way... All the energy for polarizing, say "positively" is lost when we want to polarize the material "negatively"? If someone can describe what is the area which correspond to hysteresis loss on the magnetic hysteresis loop below it would be wonderful!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange. For your first question, please use the search field. This is already answered here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/370466/area-in-hysteresis-loop-energy-lost

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/217738/123208